# automatic execution of sqlplus scrpts, use set lines, spool commands to create an out put file with the required layout using c#

Tags: c#, oracle, command-line-arguments, sqlplus

I'm developing a c# application to automatically execute sqlplus. I would like to find a way to use the set lines, set pages.. and spool command to create an output file of the proper format and layout. 
here is a code i used to run sqlplus from cmd using c#

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
processInfo.Arguments = "username/password@database @scriptFilePath";
Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

how can i incorporate and use those commands i mentioned above? Help!

Comment: Why can't you have the `set` and `spool` in the file the query is in, `scriptFilePath`? If you want to control where the output goes you can use `spool &1` and pass that as a second argument to SQL*Plus.

Comment: how exactly can i include the set and spool commands with their arguments in the script file? and could you please tell me what &1 stands for?

Comment: thank you very much! i included the commands in the script and it works fine.

Comment: `&1` is a positional parameter, somewhat similar to `argv[0]`. You can pass arguments to the SQL script from the command line; the description [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#CACIIEDF) is referring to issuing a `start` when already in SQL*Plus, but it's the same when running a script with `@`. You can use the parameter pretty much anywhere in the file, not just in the query, e.g. in the spool. If you have a fixed destination then you don't need this, but if you wanted to change the destination from c# then you could pass it as another argument.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx) property to `true` and then write to [Process.StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- Bring the window to front
- Send the keys

Like following:

```
Process sqlplus = Process.Start(processInfo);
sqlplus.WaitForInputIdle();

IntPtr hWindow = sqlplus.MainWindowHandle;
ShowWindow(hWindow, 1 /*toggle*/);

SendKeys.SendWait("SELECT * FROM...");
SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
```

Comment: @Daniel: May be I dint understand the requirement? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Have a look at my solution. That's the normal way to write to the standard input of a console application. What you are doing is like entering the house through the closed window when there is a wide open door, so to speak...

Comment: Besides, it is pretty sensible. What if the user types something as that code is executed? What if the program from the OP is running in the background and the user is using another program? Suddenly, there is a black box that grabs its focus. Pretty bad user experience.